# Static type-checking of dynamic types not sharing an interface in C#

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

Say I have some external classes that have methods sharing a signature by convention, but that do not implement an interface:

```
class A {
  public string getError();
}

class B {
  public string getError();
}
```

If I want to create a utility function that accepts objects of either type, I could use `dynamic`:

```
void printError(dynamic obj) {
  Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", obj.getError());
}
```

But if I passed a some class `C` without a `getError` method, this would be a runtime error.  Given that I can't modify `A` or `B` (directly), is there a way to implement this so that it would be a compile-time error to pass a type without a `getError` method, similar to what we'd get with C++ templates?

Comment: Couldnt you just have an overload for each type? `printError(A obj)` and `printError(B obj)`

Comment: Another option is to write wrapper classes that do share a common interface.

Comment: Alternatively, `void printError(Func<string> getErrorFunc)` and invoke it like `printError(new A().getError)`? Of course that becomes a pain if the convension is more complex than this example.

Comment: you may also check `obj.GetType().GetMethod("getError") != null` (though it does not ensure that there is no parameter, and that is it returns string)

Comment: @maccettura Repeating the logic for every type defeats the purpose.

Comment: Is there a reason these classes can't implement an interface?

Comment: @JakeCobb not when you refactor the logic into its own function and pass the result of your getError() function.  This is a tenant of OOP

Comment: Take it as a language lawyer question please.  Is it possible or not?

Comment: @JakeCobb no, its not unless you implement common interface

Comment: @JakeCobb I posted an answer already, it should be what you are looking for

Comment: @JakeCobb As a language lawyer question, my understanding is that it is not possible. Because `printError()` only sees `dynamic obj`, it has no way of knowing which methods `obj` might contain - it could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use more than one prototype

You can of course define more than one prototype, where each prototype accepts a different class. The compiler will automatically pick the method signature that matches. Example:

```
public static void PrintError(ExternalClasses.A a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.getError());
}
public static void PrintError(ExternalClasses.B b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.getError());
}
```

### Use a single prototype, but with implicit conversion

Another approach would be to define your own class and set up implicit conversion:

```
public class ErrorContainer
{
    protected string _error = null;

    public string getError()
    {
        return _error;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return getError();
    }

    static public implicit operator ErrorContainer(ExternalClasses.A a)
    {
        var e = new ErrorContainer();
        e._error = a.getError();
        return e;
    }
    static public implicit operator ErrorContainer(ExternalClasses.B b)
    {
        var e = new ErrorContainer();
        e._error = b.getError();
        return e;
    }
}
```

Then you can define PrintError to accept an ErrorContainer:

```
public static void PrintError(ErrorContainer e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

...which allows you to "pass" either type:

```
var a = new ExternalClasses.A();
PrintError(a);

var b = new ExternalClasses.B();
PrintError(b);
```

Under the covers, of course, both `A` and `B` are converted to an `ErrorContainer`.

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LemcVp)

Comment: Thanks for the example showing how to impose an interface of sorts with implicit conversion.  Reading between the lines of these two answers, it seems enumerating the types with boilerplate code is the only way to get static type safety here, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have an XY Problem.  Instead of figuring out how to make your code less type safe, why not just use a overloads and refactor?

```
public void PrintError(A obj) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", obj.getError());
    //maybe some more logic
}

public void PrintError(B obj) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", obj.getError());
    //maybe some more logic
}
```

The above code solves your problem, but its no longer DRY.  This is where we refactor:

```
public void PrintError(A obj) 
{
    PrintError(obj.getError());
}

public void PrintError(B obj) 
{
    PrintError(obj.getError());
}

//This is private, so you can only call PrintError publicly with an A or B instance
private void PrintError(string error)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", error);
    //maybe some more logic
}
```

Now you have type safety, you aren't repeating yourself and you are not "fighting the language" by using it in a way counter to how it was designed.